# Using multiple versions of same package

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install different forks of github repo. Is it possible that I install the two in single distribution and somehow use both of them as well?

```
https://github.com/abhigenie92/python-goose
https://github.com/grangier/python-goose
```

Comment: Generally not possible, unless you have them as separate package names.

Comment: @metatoaster How can I change the package name in this case, if that is the only alternative.

Comment: It also depends on how you are using the different packages - if you want features from both classes your best bet is to fork the head project and merge in the patches with the features from both those forks into your own one if you want to hack on it. Otherwise I recommend finding a different package to do what you want.

Comment: Do both have to be available at the same time to a single program?  If not it is safer to use a virtual environment.

Comment: @cdarke yes both have to availabe at the same time in a single program.

Comment: @metatoaster Both packages are completely different in their approach. I want to avoid merging them. Also, some of code is someone else which take time to crack. But ideally what you are saying should be followed.

Comment: @metatoaster: in general, it is possible e.g., setuptools' `pkg_resources.require()` but it doesn't apply to forks that use the same name and the same version: `abhigenie92/python-goose` is a fork of `grangier/python-goose` that introduced a commit -- I don't see what "packages" OP talks about: it is a single package and  the same package version. If the changes are not meant to be commited back then the fork should change the package name.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That would mean modifying this line https://github.com/grangier/python-goose/blob/develop/setup.py#L56 to different package name and then importing it as that?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: no. `grangier/python-goose` is upstream of `abhigenie92/python-goose`. The later should change the name if it is a persistent fork. Given the level of understanding you've demonstrated, you shouldn't introduce new packages: just put the forks into different directories along side your code (*vendor* them e.g., like `pip._vendor.requests`) so that absolute module names will be different. You should provide more context on why do you need to use two forks in the same program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I haven't used `git` or `pip` much. I want to extract articles from webpages. The main module renders no text sometimes in that case I use other one. Can you please explain more on your approach.

Comment: have your tried to [open a new issue](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-issue/) (for https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) in cases where it fails (in your opinion)? Have your tried to [submit a pool request with the changes](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/)?

Comment: The approach is very simple (it is not  about `git` or `pip` -- it was just an example). Create `_vendor/abhigenie92` directory along side your code and put the corresponding `goose` directory tree there: `your_project/your_package/_vendor/abhigenie92/goose`. To import it, use `from your_package._vendor.abhigenie92 import goose`.